# djNumberTextBox Validation in XPages

Tags: validation, xpages, client-side

I cannot validate a field in type of djNumberTextBox. I need to know that field has a value.
I tried this below but I cannot manage if the field is empty or not.

```
//var cFld = dijit.byId("#{id:Total}");
var aFld = dojo.byId("#{id:Total}");
if (aFld!= "")
{
    alert("Please fill the field");
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code works for me.

But, it's better to use djNumberTextBox control's property `required="true"` and to set the message text as dojoAttribute:

```xml
<xe:djNumberTextBox
    id="Total"
    value="#{sessionScope.test}"
    required="true">
    <xe:this.dojoAttributes>
        <xp:dojoAttribute
            name="missingMessage"
            value="Please fill the field!" />
    </xe:this.dojoAttributes>
</xe:djNumberTextBox>
```

It tests for value *on client side* and shows the message "Please fill the field!" if the value is empty. Instead of an ugly alert box you get the message right next to your input field like this:[image]

Comment: Thank you It works great. I did all validation of fields in CSJS. That's what i asked :) But your answer looks better as visual :))